# My external javascript is not executed

Tags: javascript, html

I try to override the `window.onload` event inside an external javascript, but even when putting some basic `console.log` line outside the `window.load` function, the code seems to never execute.

Jumping to code here it is :
for `index.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Experimentation</title>
    <script src="canvasEntry3D.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="720" width="1280"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

for `canvasEntry3D.js` :

```
console.log("slkdfnsdnflknegs");
window.onload = abcdefg;
function abcdefg() {
     console.log("in start");
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
}
```

To really know if the browser has loaded the correct javascript file, I have already checked the developper console.

And I'm not searching to override two times the `window.onlad` event, so there's no need to use addEventListeners (and there is also no other javascript code that override the `window.onload` event)

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Do you get any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but in the developper console, when I look for the network tab, it show exactly the `canvasEntry3D.js` that I have in my workspace.

Comment: So no 404 and yes `canvasEntry3D.js` is in the same folder as my `index.html`

Comment: @gurvinder372 I don't think it is a duplicate, in the question you linked he was using two onload functions, and the second one was overriding the first one.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Cristy did not find the source of the problem, I do not have any 404 errors in the console!

Comment: Try to change your script attribute to 'text/javascript' from 'type/javascript'

Comment: Does it work if you put the javascript code in the page (without external js)?

Comment: @WaKai thanks a lot mate ! It was that, I was doing some undo/redo frenetically and the type was reset to the wrong string `type/javascript`.

Comment: @WaKai and the correct string is indeed `text/javascript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake in your code I see is the wrong type attribute within your script tag.

Just change it from

```
<script src="canvasEntry3D.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="canvasEntry3D.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Ha Ha. Awesome Wa kai. You eye power is really great!